# How to change variable in filepath in R?

Tags: r, addition, raster, filepath, tiff

I have this sampled code where I want to change multiple variable outside of my filepath "S2_B8"(month,tile..) and do not have to the change the entire filepath just the variable. For example for "month" I will just have to write "01" if I wanted to take the .tif of January

```
`month <- "01"

tile <- "T39LTF"

name_im <- "AMBARO_T39LTF"

S2_B8 = raster("D:/Tuiles_José/2021/'month'/'name_im'/images/SENTINEL2X_2021+'month'+01-000000-000_L3A_+'tile'+_C_V2-2/SENTINEL2X_2021+'month'+01-000000-000_L3A_+'tile'+_C_V2-2_FRC_B8.tif",values=T)
crs(S2_B8)=crs("+init=epsg:32738")`
```

I've already done this on spyder with adding +'name_of_the_variable'+ but it does not work with R. I think that R does not understand my way because of a syntaxic error

thanks for ur help !!

Comment: In R you can't glue strings together using `+` as you could do in Python or .... But you could use `paste0`, i.e. `paste0("D:/Tuiles_José/2021/", month, "...")`. You may also have a look at the `glue` package which allows to do `glue("D:/Tuiles_José/2021/{month}/...")`

Comment: All good !! It works with glue thanks to Stefan !